# Prove weak convergence of a sequence of discrete random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

People, I have no idea how to start proving weak converge. I know the definition that limit of distribution of $X_n$ should be equal to distribution of $X$. BUT no idea how to prove it. 
I think that there should be some hint with summation.

So we have: $P(X_n=i/n)=1/n$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, and I need to show this:
$X_n \rightsquigarrow X$.

I think it is obvious that if for example $$\begin{align*}m P(X_n \leq 5/10) &= P(X_n = 1/10) + P(X_n = 2/10)  + P(X_n = 3/10) \\ &\quad + P(X_n = 4/10) + P(X_n = 5/10) \\ &= 5/10, \end{align*}$$ and $P(X\leq 5/10) = 5/10$ for $X$ uniformly distributed from $0$ to $1$.

So their distribution functions agree on $x=5/10$, and they agree on any value I choose. But in principle why this example says that we have weak convergence? Why strong convergence here does not work?

Picture for $X_{2n}(x)$ and $X_{2n+1}(x)$: 
I can not see how both sequences converge to different values. But the value of distribution function is equal 1 if we take x=1. Am I right? This is what I conclude from the picture:
[image]

Comment: Please tell the name of  ⌊…⌋notation, or explain what is it. I think this will be useful.

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the ceiling function.

Comment: By the way, the values of the distribution functions do *not* agree for any value; see my answer below.

Comment: By the other example, you created 2 limits at the end of the interval[0,1], am I right? 1 for even(which is 1) and 1 for odd(which is 0)?

Comment: For both random variables (i.e. $X_{2n}$ and $X_{2n+1}$) the corresponding distribution function has the property that it equals $1$ at $x=1$. However, the random variables $X_{2n}$ and $X_{2n+1}$ have different values close to $x=1$. (Btw: Drawing a picture is really helpful.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The distribution function $F_n := \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq x)$ equals

$$F_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < \frac{1}{n}, \\ \frac{1}{n}, & x \in \big[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n} \big) \\ \frac{2}{n}, & x \in \big[ \frac{2}{n}, \frac{3}{n} \big) \\ \vdots & \\ 1, & x \geq 1. \end{cases}$$

Letting $n \to \infty$ shows $$F_n(x) \to \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0, \\ x, & x \in [0,1] \\ 1 & x>1 \end{cases}$$ Since the right-hand side is the distribution function of a $U[0,1]$-distributed random variables, this finishes the proof.

To see that pointwise convergence does in general not hold consider the following sequence of random variables on $[0,1]$ (endowed with the Lebesgue measure)

$$X_{2n}(x) := \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n}, & x \in \big[0,\frac{1}{n} \big) \\ \frac{2}{n}, & x \in \big[ \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n} \big) \\ \vdots & \\ 1, & x \in \big[ \frac{n-1}{n}, 1 \big]. \end{cases}$$

and

$$X_{2n+1}(x) :=  \begin{cases} 1, & x \in \big[0,\frac{1}{n} \big) \\ 1- \frac{1}{n}, & x \in \big[ \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n} \big) \\ \vdots & \\ \frac{1}{n}, & x \in \big[ \frac{n-1}{n}, 1 \big). \end{cases} $$

Then $X_n \sim F_n$, but $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge pointwise.

Comment: +1. The very same idea can be given a more concise form, defining $Y_n=n^{-1}\lfloor nU\rfloor$ for every $n$, with $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$, then $X_{2n}=Y_{2n}$ and $X_{2n+1}=1-Y_{2n+1}$ for every $n$.

Comment: @Did Yeah, I wanted to avoid the $\lfloor \dots \rfloor$ notation; in my experience it scares most people ;).

Comment: Ah... OK. $ $ $ $

Comment: I am sorry, but can you elaborate more on "Letting $n \to \infty $ shows" ?  A guy said that I am beating a dead dog, but still uncertainty in my head remains. Maybe you have no experience with such problems, but know I feel more like - i believe you without understanding, than, you are right and I know it. Thank you for meticulous reply.

Comment: @Ievgenii $F_n$ is a step function ... draw a picture. Then you will understand why it converges to $F(x) = x$ (for $x \in [0,1]$).

Comment: @levgenii More precisely, given $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose $N$ such that $\frac1N<\varepsilon$. Then for $n\geqslant N$, we have $|F_n(x) - x| < \frac1n<\varepsilon$.