# Prove that $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} U[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on {$0,\ldots,n$} for each $n$:
$$P(X_n=k/n)=\frac{1}{n+1},{\space}k=0,\ldots,n$$ Prove that $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} U[0,1]$, so that continuous uniform distributions are limits of discrete. So as far I understand $F_{X_n}(t)\to F_X(t)$ as $n\to \infty$ has to be true for continuous case for distribution convergence. I am given discrete probability function (cumulative distribution function). I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1481862/

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

For $t\in(0,1)$:

$$P\left(X_{n}\leq t\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor nt\rfloor}\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{\lfloor nt\rfloor+1}{n+1}\in\left(\frac{nt}{n+1},\frac{nt+1}{n+1}\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Convergence in distribution is implied by convergence of the characteristic functions.

Comment: Do you mean something like this $F_{X_n}(t)=E[1_{(-\infty, t)}X_n]$